# devise-security gem Devise controller not found, rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Using [devise-security](https://github.com/devise-security/devise-security) gem

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError at /

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"devise/password_expired"}
```

In app/models/user.rb

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable,
         :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable, 
         :password_expirable, :password_archivable, :session_limitable, :expirable, # devise-security extension gem
         timeout_in: 45.minutes
```

In config/initializers/devise-security.rb

```
 Devise.setup do |config|
  # ==> Security Extension
  # Configure security extension for devise

  # Should the password expire (e.g 3.months)
  config.expire_password_after = 3.months

  # Need 1 char of A-Z, a-z and 0-9
  config.password_regex = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/

  # How many passwords to keep in archive
  config.password_archiving_count = 5

  # Deny old password (true, false, count)
  config.deny_old_passwords = true


  # Time period for account expiry from last_activity_at
  config.expire_after = 90.days
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users,
controllers: { registrations: "registrations", sessions: "sessions", passwords: "passwords" },
path_names: {sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}
```

rake routes

```
                          new_user_session GET                       /users/login(.:format)                                                            sessions#new
                          user_session POST                      /users/login(.:format)                                                            sessions#create
                  destroy_user_session DELETE                    /users/logout(.:format)                                                           sessions#destroy
                     new_user_password GET                       /users/password/new(.:format)                                                     passwords#new
                    edit_user_password GET                       /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                    passwords#edit
                         user_password PATCH                     /users/password(.:format)                                                         passwords#update
                                       PUT                       /users/password(.:format)                                                         passwords#update
                                       POST                      /users/password(.:format)                                                         passwords#create
              cancel_user_registration GET                       /users/cancel(.:format)                                                           registrations#cancel
                 new_user_registration GET                       /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                          registrations#new
                edit_user_registration GET                       /users/edit(.:format)                                                             registrations#edit
                     user_registration PATCH                     /users(.:format)                                                                  registrations#update
                                       PUT                       /users(.:format)                                                                  registrations#update
                                       DELETE                    /users(.:format)                                                                  registrations#destroy
                                       POST                      /users(.:format)                                                                  registrations#create
                 user_password_expired GET                       /users/password_expired(.:format)                                                 devise/password_expired#show
                                       PATCH                     /users/password_expired(.:format)                                                 devise/password_expired#update
                                       PUT                       /users/password_expired(.:format)                                                 devise/password_expired#update
```

stack trace:

```
 Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-01 13:27:54 +0100
Processing by MyEngine::DashboardController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Update All (2.7ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_activity_at" = '2018-05-01 12:27:54.495467' WHERE "users"."id" = 1
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)



ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"devise/password_expired"}
```

UPDATE:

```
    # path for change password
    def change_password_required_path_for(resource_or_scope = nil)
      scope       = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
      change_path = "#{scope}_password_expired_path"
      send(change_path)
    end
```

(change_path is "user_password_expired_path")

It works only if I change

```
send(change_path)
```

to

```
main_app.send(change_path)
```

Comment: Please give more details about error. When it occurs? Show the stack trace if available.

Comment: I added a stack trace